# Regex issues using Pattern-matching in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working with regex's using the RegEx.replace method and I'm running into some strings my patterns are not working for.

For strings such as:

```
"Av.Av. Italy"
"Av.  Av. Italy"
"Av. . Av. Italy"
```

I'm trying to replace the Av's and remove all the extra periods and whitespaces so I tyr to use this regex

```
 rgx = new Regex(@"(Av\.).(Av\.)");
 address = rgx.Replace(address, replacement);
```

[edit]
I want all of the above strings to end up just saying

```
"Av. Italy"
```

But it doesn't change anything.

I also wanted to use a regex to get random periods that appear on some strings (eg: "word . other word") with

```
rgx= new Regex(@"\b\.\b");
```

But that doesn't do anything either...

Am I using the escape sequences wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of how `Av. . Av. Italy` should end up like?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that, added it now; sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use this regex:

```
rgx = new Regex(@".*(?:(Av\.)\s*)+");
address = rgx.Replace(address, replacement);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cQ4oH6)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/O6JpSp)

The regex takes any characters, where there's an `Av.` somewhere ahead, eats all the duplicate `Av.` and spaces and replaces those with a single `Av.` (plus a space that got eaten by the regex).

---

For the second one, maybe that?

```
rgx= new Regex(@" \.(?= )");
```

`\b` matches between two word characters, namely between `\w` and `\W` no matter in what order they come, and `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` while `\W` is the opposite. Since both space and `.` are in `\W`, you wouldn't have a match. Then, I used a space instead of `\s` because `\s` matches newlines, which I don't think is what you're looking for :)

The lookahead is to prevent the removal of two white spaces. Otherwise `Word . Word` would become `WordWord`.

Comment: The first regexp works perfectly and is just what I wanted, thank you!
The second one, however didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @ConnorU Are you sure? `Word . word` has to become `Word word` right? I made a [demo](http://ideone.com/1dsE3W). Otherwise, let me know what you're really expecting!

Comment: Yes, you are right. `word . word` does become `word word`. i'm getting an error with random .'s at the end of strings [so word . \newline] but I should be able to handle that. Thanks

Comment: @ConnorU Oh, I guess that's something that will require I see the code to debug that part ^^;. Hopefully you'll be able to get it fixed `(^.^)b` Good luck!

Comment: I figured out how to fix that. One question though, the regex you gave me to take care of .'s between words also kills any numbers between words -- `The 5 soldiers` becomes `The Soldiers`. How do I avoid matching numbers?

Comment: @ConnorU Whu- No way! Are you using `@` and escaping the `.` properly as such: `\.`? It's not making any replacements [here](http://ideone.com/5Euqc7).

Comment: Scratch that. I fixed it. It's just replacing the . with a D. I used a lowercase d first and it didn't work so I was confused. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

For the first this `rgx = new Regex(@"(Av\.*[\s]*)*");` will work for you. For the second you must provide an example.

Comment: You can take the third string I posted as an example, with that random . in between the "Av."'s

Other examples: "Edinburgh . Plaza", "Av. . France"

Comment: I tried your suggestion, this is the output I got: 
`"AvAvItaly\n
Av.\n
AvAvAvAv."`...

Comment: I missed a dot `rgx = new Regex(@"(Av\.*[\s.]*)*");`. The third you mean this: "Av. . Av. Italy"?

Comment: Lol, that regex gives me `Av.v1Av8Av. AvdAveAv. AvJAvuAvlAviAvoAv. Av.
Av.v1Av8Av. AvdAveAv. AvJAvuAvlAviAvoAv. Av.
Av.Av8Av. AvdAveAv. AvjAvuAvlAviAvoAv.` :p

Comment: Ok, what do you suppose to see? What is the final string after the replacement? You want to match only the Av without dots? The regex above much all of them.

Comment: @dimimpou: The outermost quantifier should be `+`, not `*`. Your pattern is matching empty strings.

Comment: I want to turn all the three strings into
"Av. Italy \n Av. Italy \n Av. Italy", which is to say, if I got an address written in any of the three formats above, I'd want them all to end up looking the same

Comment: @dimimpou is right. I tried your regex with his correction and it worked great. Thanks to both of you